# Handling nulls in parameterized query postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've got a sql query where I'm using the sqlalchemy text function because I have a rather long and complicated query. I'd like to keep this discussion to bits about how I can handle it using compositional sql, unless its for some reason unsolvable that way.

right now, one of my subqueries uses a syntax like this

```
select * 
from table_a
join table_b on table_a.b_id = table_b.id
join table_c on table_c.b_id = table_b.id
where table_a.timestamp BETWEEN to_date(:time_range_start,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'::text) and to_date(:time_range_end,'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'::text)
AND table_a.id = ANY(:a_ids)
AND table_a.attribute_id = ANY(:attribute_ids)
AND table_b.id = ANY(:b_ids)
```

So what I need to understand is either
1. A default value to give to the ANY() function so that it essentially makes it not filter
2. A way to conditionally format in that portion of the query into the text

I could potentially just use a python string format before calling the text() function on it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a direct string format is a bad idea, that's how injection happens.

Perhaps add a boolean value to the `ANY` conditions such that you can force them to be `TRUE` (and therefore not filter). For example.

```
...
AND (:force_a_id OR table_a.id = ANY(:a_ids))
AND (:force_a_attr OR table_a.attribute_id = ANY(:attribute_ids))
...
```

However, I would really recommend using SQLAlchemy's query API, this is well within the set of problems it solves.

Comment: Composing a query from *static* bits of SQL is not usually a vector for injection, though a bit unwieldy.

Comment: True, but there's lots of tricky stuff the bad guys can do to you (esp. in a language with loose types) if you're not careful. For [example](https://twitter.com/xxbyte/status/951499972582703104?lang=en)

Comment: Note the word *static*. You can safely piece together SQL as long as it is not built from data provided from the outside (such as table and column names). It is what SQLAlchemy does under the hood. I'm not saying it's a nice approach, though, but sometimes necessary.

Comment: But you are spot on in that OPs problem is what SQLA query building capabilities are for.

Comment: the sample SQL here would be fine in SQLA builder, but the full query I had was significantly complicated and I couldn't figure out how ot put it in the builder effectively.
I have been using the sqlalchemy text() function instead because I thought that it protects against injection somewhat as well.

Comment: I actually solved the problem by just checking if certain input parameters were null or not, and formatting in the static portion of the where clause before calling text() on the string, then passing the appropriate parameters at execution.